# Mic Audio Peaks At Low Volume Logitech G430

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

So I initially bought the G430 headset for recording purposes around last October. I noticed that the audio from the mic would peak at very low volume making it difficult to record commentary without the audio quality taking a dive.

In Audacity, the volume goes to about 0.5 when it should be going to near 1.0. Here's a link to a video I recorded to show exactly what I mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfFGshPcNsQ

I get the mic a little closer then I normally do but you can see the audio peaks quite low. Even when I move the mic as far from my mouth as possible, you can still hear peaking, especially when I slightly raise my voice. If anyone can help me with this I would be very appreciative.

Comment: I like this question, but I can't seem to reproduce the problem. Are you sure this happens only in Ubuntu? Do you have another machine you can test the mic on. Is there a "audio limit" switch on the headset itself that maxes the volume? I've gone through and messed with pulseaudio, alsamixer, and audacity, and I'm unable to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started testing the headset on a windows to see if it was an ubuntu problem. After a bit of testing, it appears it's an issue with the USB adapter being faulty. I thought I tested it after I replaced my Motherboard but it appears that I didn't. Either way thanks for the help.